Dynamic Feature contain entry MainDispatcherFactory with different content
I have an Android application with dynamic feature, I am trying to build a release version to test the app on Google Play Console:
I get this error while building:
 Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolWorkAction
   > Modules 'base' and 'QuranResources' contain entry 'root/META-INF/services/kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory' with different content.

and this is the build.gradle.kts for the module:
plugins {
    id("com.android.dynamic-feature")
}

android {
    namespace = "mohalim.islamic.alarm.alert.quranresources"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 26
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":app"))

}

In the base App build gradle I am using these dependencies
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.0")
implementation("androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.9.0")

setting.gradle.kts contains:
rootProject.name = "Moazen"
include(":app")
include(":QuranResources")

I would be grateful if you could help me to solve this issue.
